# No route matches [GET] error when sending a post request with ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Sending a post request via ajax but getting the error above, "No route matches [GET]".

ajax looks like this

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/stage_progress',
   data: {'subject_id' : subject, 'course_id' : course, "chapter_id" : chapter, "stage_id" : stage, "user_id" : user, "session" : "0", "completed" : "true"},
   success: function(){
       console.log('got it');
   }
});
```

routes.rb

```
post '/stage_progress', to: 'stage_progress#track_progress'
```

If I run rake routes it shows that a post route to this url exists but for some reason the ajax is creating a "get" request.  Any help explaining why and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you move up your `url` property up and please check your routes also..

Comment: or you can just `as` block in your routes to make sure you have proper routes like this way `post '/stage_progress', to: 'stage_progress#track_progress', as:start_progress`

Comment: If you open the network tab of your browser, does the ajax request look right?  Does it hit the right url, and is it actually a POST?  That will tell you whether the problems is on the client side (if it's sending a GET somehow), or the server side (in which case it's probably a routes issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking into your code, you are overriding the default index action of your controller 'stage_progress'. Calling '/stage_progress' will only route to the default index action(get). I guess you either rename the route '/stage_progess' to something else and that would solve the issue.

Or in other case you still want the same route, then try writing it above all other routes,

```
post '/stage_progress', to: 'stage_progress#track_progress'
resources 'stage_progress'
```

Because the routes are always mapped from top to bottom in the routes.rb file. If there is any other 'GET' route above the 'POST' route declaration, it will still take only the first route configured.